# IAM SDK AmazonIdentityManagement; Status Code: 404; Error Code: NoSuchEntity;

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-java-sdk

```java
AmazonIdentityManagementClient identityManagementClient = new AmazonIdentityManagementClient();

System.out.println("This is the role");
GetRoleResult roleResult = identityManagementClient.getRole(new GetRoleRequest().withRoleName("myRole"));
System.out.println(roleResult.getRole().toString());

System.out.println("This is the Policy");       
GetRolePolicyResult rolePolicyResult  = identityManagementClient.getRolePolicy(new GetRolePolicyRequest()
        .withRoleName("myRole").withPolicyName("AmazonS3FullAccess"));

System.out.println(rolePolicyResult.getPolicyDocument());
System.out.println(rolePolicyResult.getPolicyName());
```

I have attached IAM role to my instance - myRole. I have attached it `AmazonS3FullAccess` policy to myRole. The above code I am using to fetch the policies associated with myRole using SDK but I am facing NoSuchEntity Exception when I try to fetch Policy. I am able to get Role name and my output is myRole but I am facing error when I try to fetch Policy details.

I don't know why.
What I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I only managed to get the policy document in an alternative way (AWS Java SDK v.1x)  - by using *getPolicyVersion* method of the *AmazonIdentityManagementClient*.

The *GetPolicyVersionRequest* for this is for the policyArn (which you can get from the policy details of the *listAttachedRolePolicies* result for your role name) and the *versionId* is from calling the *getDefaultVersionId()* on the policy returned by the *AmazonIdentityManagementClient* 's *getPolicy* for your policyArn.